# Convert sql to entity in query syntax

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity

How can i convert the following query to entity framework in query syntax..

> SELECT MIN(Date) StartDate, MAX(Date) EndDate, Title, Flag FROM
>   Holiday GROUP BY Title, Flag

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a hard time i get the solution

```
(from e in db.Holidays
 group e by new {e.Title, e.Flag}
 into g
 select new AllEventViewModel
 {
 start = g.Max(e=>e.Date),
 end = g.Min(e => e.Date),
 title = g.Key.Title,
 Flag = g.Key.Flag
 }).AsEnumerable();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = db.holidays.GroupBy(g => new { g.Title, g.Flag }).Select(k => new
{
    MinDate = k.Min(a => a.Date),
    StartDate = k.FirstOrDefault().StartDate,
    MaxDate = k.Max(b => b.Date),
    EndDate = k.FirstOrDefault().EndDate,
    Title = k.Key.Title,
    Flag = k.Key.Flag
}).ToList();
```